# com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to register with firabase in android. I am getting some errors.

The error says :

> com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Access Not Configured. Google Identity Toolkit API has not been used in project '' before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/overview?project='' then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

and this

> Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.

I searched error on google but still could not find a solution. I am waiting your helps.

Project build.gradle:

```
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.nagchat"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

and my RegisterActivity.class

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextInputLayout mDisplayName;
    private TextInputLayout mEmail;
    private TextInputLayout mPassword;
    private Button mCreateRegBtn;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    void init(){
        mDisplayName = (TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.reg_display_name);
        mEmail = (TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
        mPassword = (TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
        mCreateRegBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRegCreate);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }

    void clickable(){
        mCreateRegBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String displayName = mDisplayName.getEditText().getText().toString();
                String email = mEmail.getEditText().getText().toString();
                String password = mPassword.getEditText().getText().toString();

                registerUser(displayName, email, password);
            }
        });
    }

    private void registerUser(String displayName, String email, String password) {
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(mainIntent);
                    finish();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "You got some error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        init();
        clickable();
    }
}
```

Comment: you have enabled the password auth in firebase console?

Comment: yes i enabled Email/Password

Comment: And in your Project you have added all files to Project like google-services.json file, I want to know if firebase is correctly implemented in your Project and you dont miss anything because for my your code is fine. And in your module build.gradle file i dont see this line: apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: I think i did not google-services.json file. I've downloaded it. Where i have to add it?

Comment: you can read this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: I solved the problem. It was my fault because i did not any log and when i logged i did take 'Weak Password' warning. It is okay now.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but the google-services.json is added, any other solution?